# Vue Router access individual getters from Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to access the currently authenticated user in my Vuex store inside my router.js file

```
{
  path: '/admin/login',
  name: 'admin-login',
  component: AdminLogin,
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    console.log(store.state.user);
    if(store.getters.user) {
      // check if an agency is trying to log in as admin
      if (!store.getters.user.attributes['custom:role_id'] === 1) {
        next({ name: 'agency-dashboard', params: { agency: store.getters.user.attributes['custom:agency_id'] } });
      } else {
        next({ name: 'admin-dashboard' });
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

When I `console.log(store.getters)` I get an object of all the properties in state including a user object.

However, when I try access `console.log(store.getters.user)`, which does exist in my store.js, it simply returns `false` which is the initial state of my user object on page load.

How come the user object is visible from `state.getters` but not `state.getters.user`?

Comment: _"How come the user object is visible from `state.getters` but not `state.getters.user`"_ - if it returns `false` then it is "visible"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me a syntax error, because getters are accessed as properties that are cached as part of the Vue's reactivity system. Use to access it:

```
this.$store.getters
```